# How to exclude a c# attribute with preprocessor directive based on platform on a netstandard library

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, msbuild

I am working on a Xamarin mobile solution.
The solution contains:

- a Xamarin.iOS project
- a netstandard2.0 project

In the netstandard2.0 project I need to change an attribute in a class depending if I am compiling for a real iPhone or for the iPhoneSimulator

something like this

```
#if _SIMULATOR_
    [AttributeForSimulator]
#else
    [AttributeForRealDevice]
#endif
public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {

    }    
}
```

I know I could do this editing the .csproj file adding:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|IPhoneSimulator' ">
    <DefineConstants>_SIMULATOR_;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The main problem is that on a netstandard2.0 library Platform can only be AnyCpu, so asking the question in a different way: is it possible to tell if the common library will be used in a project running on the IphoneSimulator or on the real Iphone?

Comment: at compile time, no

Comment: can it works for u ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.islocal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_IsLocal

Comment: in order to conditionally compile something, the information surely needs to be provided to the compiler, which is done using the csproj-properties. So, no, there's no way around that.

Comment: So even if when I select Debug|IphoneSimulator when I run the solution there is no way to propagate this information to the library. That's a pity :(